# SSH-forwarding during build only works for root

Tags: git, docker, ssh, bitbucket

Here's a Dockerfile that works:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.0.0-experimental
FROM debian:buster-slim as base

# setup APT operation for noninteractive use
# This avoids a bunch of warnings like
# "debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog"
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# install requirements
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        git \
        openssh-client

# add a user
# RUN adduser --disabled-password app-user
# WORKDIR /home/app-user
# USER app-user

RUN mkdir --mode=0700 ~/.ssh
RUN printf "Host <bitbucket host>\n  StrictHostKeyChecking no\n  CheckHostIP no\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
RUN chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
RUN --mount=type=ssh ssh-keyscan -t rsa <bitbucket host> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN chmod 600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone --no-checkout 'ssh://git@<bitbucket host>/my/project.git'
```

The only thing I edited out is the actual Bitbucket host. Now, what doesn't work is activating the three commands following the "add a user" comment. If these three commands are activated, build fails with:

```
#20 [13/13] RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone --no-checkout 'ssh://git@bitbucke...
#20       digest: sha256:2ca1...
#20         name: "[13/13] RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone --no-checkout 'ssh://git@<bitbucket host>/my/project.git'"
#20      started: 2020-03-31 20:12:44.957895838 +0000 UTC
#20 0.648 Cloning into 'project'...
#20 1.170 git@<bitbucket host>: Permission denied (publickey).
#20 1.171 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
#20 1.171 
#20 1.171 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
#20 1.171 and the repository exists.
#20    completed: 2020-03-31 20:12:46.235264455 +0000 UTC
#20     duration: 1.277368617s
#20        error: "executor failed running [/bin/sh -c git clone --no-checkout 'ssh://git@<bitbucket host>/my/project.git']: exit code: 128"

rpc error: code = Unknown desc = executor failed running [/bin/sh -c git clone --no-checkout 'ssh://git@<bitbucket host>/my/project.git']: exit code: 128
```

Is this a bug in Docker? Am I missing an implication that this is not supposed to work somehow? Do I need to set up an additional level of forwarding between the root account and the new user account? How does git/ssh establish the communication to the agent in the first place? I checked `/tmp`, `/run`, mounts and the environment but couldn't find a pipe/socket.

The obvious workaround is to clone as root and then run `chown -R` on it, but that that seems very unelegant. Also, I'd obviously like to understand what's going on.

Comment: Does adding a sub-option `--mount=type=ssh,uid=1000` (matching the numeric user ID of `app-user`) work?  It looks like [the `uid` defaults to 0](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md#run---mounttypessh) which would make the forwarded agent socket inaccessible to a non-root user.

Comment: I believe that would be the answer, @DavidMaze. However, I'd rather use the `mode` sub-option. I'll have to upgrade from 18.09 though, because that version doesn't understand either of the two variants.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Buildkit [`--mount=type=ssh`](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#run---mounttypessh) directive remounts the host's ssh agent socket into the container with specific permissions.  The default is owned by root (uid=0, gid=0) and unreadable by any other user (mode=0600).

You can add an option to make the socket be owned by some known non-root user:

```sh
# When you create the user specify its uid
RUN adduser --disabled-password --uid 999 app-user
USER app-user

# Also specify the uid as a mount option
RUN --mount=type=ssh,uid=999 ssh-keyscan ...
```

You could also make the socket accessible by other users (not a huge security concern, since it's only accessible for the lifetime of the single `RUN` command and you control what it's running)

```sh
RUN --mount=type=ssh,mode=0666 ssh-keyscan ...
```

Comment: Can you by any chance point me to the documentation that explains the part about adding `mode` or `uid` options? I've been scouring for this solution and your answer is the only clue I've found.

Comment: I corrected the link in the first line of the answer.  That documents the additional options, though you need to look at some of the other examples to see the syntax.